# How were S.H.I.E.L.D. resources available to The Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we saw that

> S.H.I.E.L.D. came out to help civilians with its Helicarrier.

That was fantastic, but the problem is:

> S.H.I.E.L.D. is having civil war right now with the Director on run (Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. TV series).

How exactly did S.H.I.E.L.D. arrange

> a Helicarrier?

Is there an another incarnation of S.H.I.E.L.D., seeing as

> Maria Hill is on-board? Note: Maria Hill joined Stark Industries last year in the TV series. Is Tony funding this other incarnation of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Comment: At the end of the (currently) last episode of shield (S02E18) there is an announcement that the next episode (S02E19) will feature an exclusive scene from Avengers: Age of ultron. This episode will therefore most likely explain shields involvement in the movie. (Added as a answers because my reputation is to low to comment)

Comment: @Kenneth: DUM DUM DUUUUUUUUUUM

Comment: Maria Hill being on the helicarrier is explained in the movie. Fury asks Stark: "Do you mind if I borrow Hill?"

Comment: @Kenneth That episode has come and gone now. There is no scene in the show that specifically explains SHIELDs involvement other than Coulson saying it's time to call the Avengers about *something* - which may or may not have to do with the movie at all.

Comment: @phantom42 Identifying the location of Loki's scepter, right at the end of the episode

Comment: Theta Protocol was a project restoring one remaining Helicarrier after the events of Winter Solder. I don't remember the Agents of Shield episode number or specific lines so in lazyness, I won't make this an actual answer.

Answer (score 13):

> As far as I can tell that was not either of the two SHIELD factions fighting in the show; it was just Nick Fury and some people who were still loyal to him. It may seem unbelievable that he was able to get his hands on a Helicarrier, but that is how Nick rolls.

One of the main features of the original Nick Fury character in the comics is his ability to hide resources for a rainy day. This includes large amounts of money, hardware and loyal personnel.

If you are interested look into the comic *Secret Warriors* (April 2009 – July 2011).

> We now know that Agent Coulson has been working with Fury all along, providing intel through Maria Hill and prepping the Helicarrier (Theta Protocol). He does not inform any of his team of this, except for the Koenigs.

I will be updating this answer as new episodes of *AoS* comes out.

Comment: You're probably right on that last point - AoS is putting a lot of emphasis on the Theta Protocol project, but all the clues so far point towards some kind of base or facility being built.

Comment: note that Coulson specifically mentions Fury "coming back" for his "toolbox" when he hands it over to Gonzalez....

Answer (score 3):

A lot of this is explained in season 2 of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

> Yes, there's another incarnation of S.H.I.E.L.D. with Coulson as a director.
>  Yes, Coulson is still alive.
>  Maria Hill is the contact person between S.H.I.E.L.D. and the Avengers.

The Sokovia helicarrier was revealed in episode 20 of season 2:

> One of the Fury's disused helicarriers was maintained as a part of the secret Theta Protocol.
>  [image: Hellicarrier in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.]
>  *Koenig: I gotta tell you, it's not easy to keep something as big as a helicarrier secret.*

See also: [What is Theta Protocol?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87658/what-is-theta-protocol)