# What is Theta Protocol?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield

We're hearing *Theta Protocol* in Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. TV series for some time (Coulson was hiding it from the team). In the last episode S02E19 of the TV series, this conversation happened regarding Theta Protocol:

> **Maria Hill:** Last Thing. Theta Protocol. Is it ready?
>  **Coulson:** Yes, it is. Time to bring in the Avengers.

What exactly is Theta Protocol? This clearly sets up the events of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie (which I have already watched), but I am unable to find a picture of Theta Protocol in the movie.

Comment: Since this question is about something that literally happened in the last 30 seconds of the most recent episode of an ongoing TV show, this clearly falls under our "future works" policy and should be closed until the answer appears on-screen; otherwise it's just inviting speculation.

Comment: Didn't Coulson answer in the dialogue you quote? From the description of the episode in Wkipedia, it seems that this episode prepares the opening scene in The Avengers 2.

Comment: You have no idea yet because the show was written specifically to augment *Age of Ultron*, but not tie into it directly.

Comment: Just because this hasn't been answered in the show doesn't make it off topic. The OP could have very well thought, like I did, that maybe Theta Protocol was a reference to some other Marvel canon. Also, given the way the last 10 minutes of the show set up the beginning of Ultron, I'd say that we have our answer, if not directly told what it was.

Comment: This was actually answered in Age of Ultron, but will likely take some explaining to connect the dots.

Comment: @Omegacron Go on.  Having just seen the film, my best guess is the last scene pre-credits.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks the phrase "Theta Protocol" has been referenced on *Agents of SHIELD* repeatedly, but it never came up once in *Age of Ultron*. To me, that means it's a future plot element in AoS, one who's answer we don't know yet (I can *guess* what it probably meant, but we don't really know.) Our site policy for not-yet-answered questions (which you can see on the meta site) is, we put them on hold until we have an answer, then reopen them.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: As I stated, and Omegacron stated, I believe we have our answer, it just wasn't spelled out for us. Theta Protocol was something to deal with the Avengers. The last episode of AoS was a direct lead into the movie. Also, as I'd stated, for myself who's never read the comics, Theta Protocol could very well have a meaning in the comics. No one has come forth with a definitive "It doesn't exist in the comics". Thus it is a candidate for reopening. It for sure shouldn't be downvoted like it has been.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks well, our policy on future-works questions is a bit quirky... if you think you have an answer and want to post it, asking on meta or in chat will likely bring an admin out to reopen the question for you to do so.

Comment: Age of Ultron was originally scheduled to be released on the Memorial Day weekend in the US (May 25th 2015,) and Agents of SHIELD episodes were scheduled accordingly - i.e. the season finale (to be broadcast on May 12th) was supposed to air first, setting up the Avengers 2 movie. For whatever reason, the release of "Ultron" was pushed up to May 1st, but the TV show air dates couldn't be changed. So now the show looks to be "behind" by 2 episodes.

Comment: Having just read a small interview from [Kevin Feige](http://collider.com/avengers-2-infinity-gauntlet-helicarrier-kevin-feige/), I believe that Theta Protocol may have something to do with the Helicarrier restoration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on last night's Agents of SHIELD, it appears that Theta Protocol had to do with the Helicarrier that was being stored in an unknown SHIELD base. One of the Koenig brothers was running the base for Coulson and Fury.

So I would assume by saying that Theta was ready, Coulson was informing Fury that the carrier was ready to be put into play if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

After the episode *Scars* (S02E20), we can definitively say that Theta Protocol was the restoration of the Helicarrier. It was kept a secret in case any other HYDRA agents were still active within SHIELD.