# How resourceful is Director Coulson at this point?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the recent episode S02E19 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*

> Director Coulson needed to infiltrate a HYDRA base to obtain some intel (and, rescue some supernaturals).

So, he surrendered himself to Robert so that he could convince the Real S.H.I.E.L.D. for the mission (at the cost of Fury's cube). They were going to provide agents and back-end support.

But, why was it needed? Director Coulson was free and he had Fury's cube. He had lost only one base. He was director of S.H.I.E.L.D. which was spread throughout the world. Why couldn't he simply pick another base to get agents and support?

---

Just after his base was attacked and he became free, why didn't he attacked his base to gain its control again? What was the point of inviting them to Banner's safe house type rat things? I mean, he was the *director* of the S.H.I.E.L.D. How could a small rebel alliance strip him out of power?

Comment: The only person who really believes he's the director of SHIELD is his team and whatever agents he got to before Gonzales; everything we've seen implies that Coulson is extremely outnumbered by the other SHIELD faction.\

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Coulson setup bases in lots of countries just after becoming Director. Remember Ward's brother's time?

Comment: Did you see the Avengers Age of Ultron? I want to answer this but I don't want to give Age of Ultron spoilers this soon.

Comment: @Christopher I am surprised on that question. Yes, I have already watched and everyone on this site know that.

Comment: Ok then from what I can tell Coulson was more concerned with setting up Theta Protocol, which we see take place in the opening of Age of Ultron. He needed the last piece to the puzzle with Theta Protocol, the location of the Baron's main hideout. Once he gets the intel from the base, he hands it over to Agent Hill so the Avengers can Assemble on the Baron.

Comment: @Christopher Can you answer this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87658/what-is-theta-protocol

Answer (score 3):

Coulson is far more resourceful than he appears. In fact, as of the end of S02E19 we find that he

> still has the backing of Maria Hill & Nick Fury.

We also see that he used his own team for the HYDRA infiltration, and did not use any resources provided by Gonzales. We can assume that Coulson involved Gonzales for three reasons:

- Coulson's plan required the use of The Bus, which was in Gonzales' possession
- Surrendering to Gonzales allowed Coulson access to his team members May & Simmons
- Surrendering to Gonzales allowed Coulson access to Gonzales' base & computers

Comment: He did destroy The Bus.. I mean his original flying HQ.. Certainly, he could find another Boeing Jet to destroy.

Comment: I'm not sure, but The Bus could be the only one that had the cloaking technology and/or could dock with the Quinjet. I remember in an early episode they said that The Bus was unique - that's why Fury was so mad about it being damaged at the end of Season 1.